# IosSlider will not allow content to be added below it

Tags: html, css, ios, slider

I would like to add content (links and text) below my slider so that the slider takes up the majority of the screen but you can scroll to see the content below it.  Here is my html with a sample div below my slider:

```
<!-- Slider -->
<section id="slider" >

<div class="container-fluid">
    
   
    <div class = 'responsiveHeight'>
        
    
        <div class = 'inner'>
            
            
            <div class = 'iosSlider'>
                
            
                <div class = 'slider'>
                
                    
                    <img class="item selected" src="../images/Project/Education-Municipal/grandcayman/01 0614-23.1491.1503.jpg"/>
                    
                    
                    <img class="item" src="../images/Project/Education-Municipal/grandcayman/02 0614-23_1350.jpg"/>
                    
                    
                    <img class="item" src="../images/Project/Education-Municipal/grandcayman/03 0614-23_DSC2008.jpg"/>
                    
                    
                    <img class="item" src="../images/Project/Education-Municipal/grandcayman/04 0614-23_DSC2130.jpg"/>
                    
                    
                    <img class="item" src="../images/Project/Education-Municipal/grandcayman/05 0614-23_G3A1975crop2.jpg"/>
                    
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class = 'prevButton'></div>
    
        <div class = 'nextButton'></div>
    
    </div>
    
</div> <!-- /.container -->
<div class = 'indicators'>
    <div class = 'item selected'></div>
    <div class = 'item'></div>
    <div class = 'item'></div>
    <div class = 'item'></div>
    <div class = 'item'></div>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the sample content I would like below the slider section:

```
<div class="container">
 <h2>Sample content I would like to appear below my slider if the user scrolls the page</h2></div>
```

Here is my CSS for the slider:

```
#slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:0px; 
    width:100%;
    color:#666;
    z-index:1;
  }
  .responsiveHeight {
            height: 0;
            padding: 0 0 34% 0; /* responsive slider height = 40% of the browser width --- moved to 35% for footer */
            position: relative;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
  .responsiveHeight > .inner {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .iosSlider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .iosSlider .slider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .iosSlider .slider img {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            padding-right:2px;
        }
```

I changed the #slider from absolute positioned to relative but no luck.  I have also tried adjusting the overflow for the responsive height as well as the over height.  Any insight would be appreciated.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can do this by setting a wrapper div set to a fixed height.   I used height of 650px and wrapped that div around the slider content.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?  I will need to adjust my height for each device so looking for a simpler solution.